# Database Create on SQL Server2008 Express/Windows VIsta Home Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, windows-vista

I successfully installed Express on Windows Vista Home Edition.  When I tried to create a database using the account under which it was installed I received this message:

TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Create failed for Database 'Test1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 262)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you need to add appropiate access to the account first, a quick googling give me this :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326612.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create it with the 'sa' user ? Also, check whether your windows user has the proper permission for this database in the sql-server settings.